# JSF bean not displaying values in xhtml page

Tags: jsf

Hi I am not able to access value in my xhtml page.I am using JSF as front end in my application.

**ProductEntity.java**

```
       String name;
       String cost;
       String mfgDate;
      // set()/get() methods
```

**ProductBean.java**

```
        private ArrayList<ProductTO> productTO = new ArrayList<ProductTO>();
         setProductTO()/getProductTO()
       init(){
     proList = proManager.getAllProduct(); //getting list of all products
     for (ProductEntity proEntity : proList) {
     ProTO proTo = new ProTO();
     proto.set(proEntity);
      .....

      } 
    productTO.add(proTo);
```

**showProduct.xhtml**

```
            <h:dataTable  value="#{product.productTO}" var="pto">

               <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText  
                                 value="productname" />           

               </f:facet>  
               <h:outputText value="#{pto.name}"/>
               </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

**pto.name value** is not getting reflected in html page. proList is getting populated but when i am accessing it in html it is not displaying the values. Please suggest some solution. Thanks !!!!

Comment: Just a little sidenote: It seems that you use custom setters to populate DTO objects from entities. Try using a Java bean mapper like Dozer (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to do this automatically with just 1 line of code for any DTO<->Entity mapping

Comment: Please add the relevant managed bean code and the Facelets/JSF code used in your page to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to fill a list with `null` elements, the `productTo.add(proTo)` procedure should be inside the `for` instruction :

```
for (ProductEntity proEntity : proList) {
    ProTO proTo = new ProTO();
    proto.set(proEntity);
      .....
    productTO.add(proTo);
}
```